# Using a function to build a PDO prepared query

Tags: php, function, pdo, prepared-statement

> number of bound variables does not match number of tokens … on line 54

I'm trying to use a function to build a pdo prepared query, but I'm getting all kinds of errors.

```
23  function get_type($a) {
24      if (is_numeric($a)) return $record_data->bindParam(":value", $a, PDO::PARAM_INT); // $a is a number
25      if (strlen($a)<1) return $record_data->bindParam(":value", "", PDO::PARAM_STR); // $a is empty
26      return $record_data->bindParam(":value", $a, PDO::PARAM_STR); // default
27  }
…
51  foreach($pair as $qstn=>$answr) {
52      $record_data = $dbh->prepare("SOME_SQL");
53      get_type($answr);
54      $record_data->execute();
55  }
```

It was working before I put the `bindParam`s into a function…I'm guessing it has something to do with the `return`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is due to the function's scope. Variables from outside a function are only usable within it if (a) they are passed in as arguments or (b) if they are imported using the `global` statement. The latter is a very bad idea.

You need to pass the statement object to your function as well as the value you want to bind:

```
function get_type($record_data, $a) {
// ...
get_type($record_data, $answr);
```

With that said, your code looks very broken. The idea of determining whether the value should be passed as an integer or a string based on its type in the application (rather than the column type of the database) seems wrong to me. <s>Also, you do a `foreach`, but only the last item in the array will be used, since you are only binding to one parameter (`:value`).  You almost certainly need to rethink your whole approach here.</s>

Comment: Ahha—Thanks! (I swear ≥25% of my issues are scope). btw, I know what kind of data the values should be. It gets complicated because columns that should contain just numbers also have to allow strings (and vice versa) because the people I'm doing this for are insane…

Comment: btw, what did you do to my question that made the colouring work?

Comment: +1 for the scope explanation, but -1 for the rest of your answer.  His loop is actually preparing and executing the query in each iteration, so each call to the `get_type()` function would be binding a new value to the `:value` parameter in a *different* statement.

Comment: @jacob I tagged it as `php`; StackOverflow guesses what language you are using based on the tags.

Comment: oh! I see (I didn't include php because PDO = PHP Data Object). Thanks!